# How to run new instance of qt application programmatically

Tags: c++, qt

Im trying to clone notepad. Im getting some trouble with the "new window"(ctrl+shift+n) button. is there a way for me to run a new instance of the application programmatically?(that is also not a child of the first instance, meaning if i close the first instance the second instance will continue to live)

(I already read about the fact that you cant call main from inside ur program so thats -1 idea)

Qt6
Windows 11

Comment: Wat version of Qt (Qt5 or Qt6)? What operating system?

Comment: Oh yea sorry i forgot to mention, im gonna edit.

Comment: ***Im getting some trouble with the "new window"(ctrl+shift+n) button.*** Can you explain further what problem you have with this. I am not sure spawning a new process is the best approach. You may just want to have more than 1 main widget.

Comment: @Reinder thnx i think thats it. one last question: what do i need to pass in as the program parameter? the "Executable.exe" for example?
Edit: nvm i did indeed have to pass the string filename of the executable. thnx for the info and for not immediately just rejecting my idea :)

Comment: @drescherjm look at reinder's post. thats prob what im looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html is what you are looking for. Expecially the startDetached method might do the trick, see: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#startDetached-1